# When I die, how much of the experience I have gained is made into orbs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I died, but very near my spawn point. When I came back to the point where I'd died (I fell to my death) there was my stuff spread around, as well as loads of experience orbs! I don't know how much I had before I died, so is the amount I just picked up:

- The exact amount I had before I died?
- Some random/fixed portion of that amount?
- Fixed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears the amount of experience lost upon dying is approximately the same as the amount of orbs that gets dropped.

> Upon the player's death, a number of Experience Orbs are dropped at the location of death. … The number of orbs that are reclaimed is about the same number as the amount lost. - [MC Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience_Orb)

---

Upon testing it myself, it seems the experience dropped *isn't equal to* the experience you had before you died. After running three tests, I usually got about 1/2 of the experience I had before I died.

This image contains three tests: the experience meter before is on top and the experience bar after is below. Also, in the third test, I had an entire bar of experience *plus* what is shown.

[image: Experience: Before and After]

Comment: When I get to a computer, I'll verify this myself in-game.

Comment: `about the same`?

Comment: @fredley Yeah, that's why I'm going to test it myself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is outdated. Could you update it? (I'd write an answer myself but I'm not sure of the exact behavior and Minecraft Wiki is vague about the actual experience total; my impression is that given sufficient starting experience you get at most about 5 levels worth.)

Comment: Yeah. I just fell on a flat surface from a very high place (so orbs and items were all recovered). Before I plunged into the abyss I was level 28. When I recovered the orbs I was level 7. Actually level 7-8 seems to be a number that comes way to often when recovering orbs at least in my case. I find it extremely annoying that there seems to be no obvious way of telling what your XP loses would be. I remember killing myself once (again - hopped into a hole and landed at the bottom due to the inability to grab the ladder in time). I was like level 40. Got approx. 7-8 levels back. Insane loss...

Answer (score 2):

The Minecraft Wiki is quite detailed about experience points and experience levels. This may not have been the case at the time the previous answer and comments were written.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience

"When the player dies, they drop experience orbs worth 7 * current level experience points, up to a maximum of 100 points (enough to reach level 7). All the other experience vanishes."

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I've died with about 900 levels and I only got 7 back.